# How get resolution of SVG image in python?

Tags: python, django, svg, python-imaging-library

Is there any way to get the resolution of an SVG image in python. All other image resolution works fine with PIL. I don't get any solution for SVG image.I am using following code to get the resolution but it works only for some cases,

```
data = request.FILES['picture']
tree = ET.parse(data)
root = tree.getroot()
h = int(root.attrib['height'])
w = int(root.attrib['width'])
print(h, w)
```

Comment: In an easy way, you can convert it to another format

Comment: SVGs are vectors. They don't have a resolution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SVG files are vectors and can be read as XML. for example, [xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) in the Python standard library can parse XML files.

We have something line this :

```
<svg width="240" height="240" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
```

If your file has width and height attributes, you can use them. Without width and height i don't think there is a way to get exactly size of SVG file because they can scale infinitely ( **any resolution** )

Width and height

```
<svg width="240" height="240" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
```

Doubles the original scale.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 120 120" width="240" height="240" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
```

Infinite scaling

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 120 120" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another alternative solution for the question.

```
import requests
from io import BytesIO
from svgpathtools import svg2paths

# URL of the SVG file
svg_url_example = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f7/Bananas.svg'


# Fetch the SVG content from the URL
response = requests.get(svg_url_example)

# Check if the request was successful
if response.status_code == 200:

    # Read the content of the SVG file
    svg_content = BytesIO(response.content)

    # Extract paths and attributes
    #paths, attributes = svg2paths(svg_content)
    attributes = svg2paths(svg_content, return_svg_attributes = True)

    print(f"SVG Width: {attributes[2]['width']}")
    print(f"SVG Height: {attributes[2]['height']}")
else:
    print("Failed to fetch the SVG file.")
```